# How to make unclickable dropdown list on google sheets with formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a document on google sheets on which I want to make an unclickable cell (that contains a dropdown list) if another cell presents the data "Existente". I saw a video of a guy using the data validation from the Data on the navigation bar, but it didnt work because when the cell was blocked, it blocked also the dropdown list, erasing the options. So I guess making the dropdown list unclickable if the other cell presents the data "Novo" is the answer.

But how can i do it??
Im not a developer (yet), please help :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUiT2.png)

I tried following this video, but he doesnt use dropdown list on the blocked cell: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGIT-IwwMwY&ab_channel=ProlificOaktree

Comment: sorry guys, i typed wrong on the first phrase: ... if another cell presents the data "Novo". I want to make clickable dropdown list if the cell is optioned as "Existente".

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with change the cell to block and change the validation formula to your cell make it unable.

like:
[image]

i forget to change "open" to "Novo", then it's should be done.